# How to store BigDecimal in Excel file Using Java

Tags: java, excel

```
Below is code
 while(resultSet.next())
  {
  Hrow=spreadsheet.createRow(i);

cell_1=Hrow.createCell(1);
cell_1.setCellValue((RichTextString) resultSet.getBigDecimal("longitude"));
cell_1=Hrow.createCell(2);
cell_1.setCellValue( (RichTextString) resultSet.getBigDecimal("latitude"));
cell_1=Hrow.createCell(3);
cell_1.setCellValue((RichTextString) resultSet.getBigDecimal("indexValueO"));

  i++;
 }
```

m fetching the data from mysql 
why m getting Class cast exception when trying to do with RichTextString ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you expect what the [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) shall be after casting. But I would use [Cell.setCellValue(java.lang.String value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue(java.lang.String)) like so:

```
...
cell_1.setCellValue(resultSet.getBigDecimal("longitude").toPlainString());
...
```

There [BigDecimal.toPlainString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--) converts `BigDecimal` to `String`.

If this not fits, there are also other string conversion methods with `BigDecimal`. See documentation.